# Integrate Angular 4+ application with ASP.NET Core SignalR

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to integrate Angular 4 + SPA with ASP.NET Core SignalR starting from [this tutorial](https://damienbod.com/2017/09/12/getting-started-with-signalr-using-asp-net-core-and-angular/).

I have managed to integrate using a simple web app (jquery + signalR client) with ASP.NET Core App, so server-side configuration seems ok.

#### ASP.NET Core

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR version 1.0.0-alpha2-final

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("chat");
});
```

**ChatHub.cs**

```
public class ChatHub: Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.InvokeAsync("broadcastMessage", name, message + " from SignalR hub");
    }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        Clients.All.InvokeAsync("broadcastMessage", "system", $"{Context.ConnectionId} joined the conversation");
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(System.Exception exception)
    {
        Clients.All.InvokeAsync("broadcastMessage", "system", $"{Context.ConnectionId} left the conversation");
        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

#### Working client

I am referencing `signalr-client-1.0.0-alpha2-final.js`

```
// Web sockets do not work, most probably due to IIS Express I am using for testing
var transport = signalR.TransportType.LongPolling;
var connection = new signalR.HubConnection(`http://localhost:60431/chat`, { transport: transport });

connection.start();
```

This works fine.

#### Angular 4+ client (non working)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';

export class SignalrTestComponent implements OnInit {

  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;

  ngOnInit() {
    let transportType = signalR.TransportType.LongPolling;
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnection('http://localhost:60431/chat', { transport: transportType });

    this.hubConnection.start()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Hub connection started')
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('Error while establishing connection')
      });
  }
```

I will receive 'Error while establishing connection'. The error is related to the fact that client tries to reach `http://localhost:60431/chat/negotiate` which returns a wrong response (some dummy text associated with an incorrect route instead of an expected JSON).

My assumption is that `transport` parameter is ignored and thus the negotiate is triggered. However, AFAIK negotiate is no longer supported in ASP.NET Core version of SignalR.

**package.json possibly relevant dependencies**

```
"@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
"@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.0-preview1-update1",
```

**Question:** How can I properly configure HubConnection to include the desired protocol when using Angular2+ client?

Comment: Could there be a possibility you have a `Chat Controller` with route to `/Chat`? If not, can you change your route to `routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat"); //Notice the / <-- forward slash`

Comment: @12seconds - the ASP.NET Core application contains no custom controllers and I have only this route. The working test uses `signalr-client-1.0.0-alpha2-final.js` and I sense an issue with `@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.0-preview1-update1` dependency. I will try to work the previous version (`alpha2`) instead of `preview1`.

Comment: @12seconds - `http://localhost:60431/chat` is resolved correctly and I receive the error `http://localhost:60431/chat` which is normal (the client must provide a connection id).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question was caused by a problem **based on an alpha version** that can no longer be reproduced — and solved by a simple upgrade to a preview version. **A stable version has since been released.** While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got help on the [project's github issue section](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1860). My server-side (ASP.NET Core SignalR) version was not up to date and thus the issues I had:

1. Upgraded to `1.0.0-preview1-final`
2. Changed server-side code to adapt to newer version (i.e. fixed compile errors):

   ```
   public class ChatHub: Hub
   {
       public void Send(string message)
       {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.SendAsync("broadcastMessage", message + " from SignalR hub");
       }
    }
   ```

As a side note the @latest version of client side package is not exactly as the server-side one:

> There was a minor issue in the JavaScript client when preview1 was
>   released and it needed to be updated, so the latest version of the
>   JavaScript client is 1.0.0-preview1-update1, but the server is
>   1.0.0-preview1-final. These versions are completely compatible.

Comment: May i know what error you experienced before updating signalr? is it "Failed to start the connection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"?

Comment: @ArulManivannan - "'Error while establishing connection" (on the client side) was the error. I did not have time to follow on this, but now it seems that they have finally released [a stable version of @aspnet/signalr]( https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `this.hubConnection.start()`, the new `@aspnet/signalr` docs say to use the following...

```
const url = 'http://www.something.com';

this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(url)
  .build();
```

The docs are still really crappy, but I have it working in my project, hope this helps.

Comment: Yes docs are not useful, received an error, Failed to start the connection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Did u overcome any?